# General error during conversion: Error grabbing Grapes download failed net.java.dev.jna

Tags: groovy, groovy-grape

groovy version 2.3.7 installed with gvm on a mac. We are behind a corporate proxy, but maven works fine for java projects here.

Tried the following

```
groovy groovySSHtest.groovy
```

contents here

```
@Grab(group='org.hidetake', module='groovy-ssh', version='1.0.1')
import org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.Ssh
def ssh = Ssh.newService()

ssh.remotes {
  mylaptop {
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    user = 'username'
    identity = new File('id_rsa')
  }
}

ssh.run {
  session(ssh.remotes.mylaptop) {
    //put 'example.war', '/webapps'
    execute 'pwd'
  }
}
```

and received the following error

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
General error during conversion: Error grabbing Grapes -- [download failed: net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.4.0!jna.jar]

java.lang.RuntimeException: Error grabbing Grapes -- [download failed: net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.4.0!jna.jar]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:71)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrap.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:81)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
        at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.getDependencies(GrapeIvy.groovy:421)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:166)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.resolve(GrapeIvy.groovy:566)
        at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy$resolve$3.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:153)
        at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.resolve(GrapeIvy.groovy:535)
        at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy$resolve$2.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
        at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.grab(GrapeIvy.groovy:252)
        at groovy.grape.Grape.grab(Grape.java:163)
        at groovy.grape.GrabAnnotationTransformation.visit(GrabAnnotationTransformation.java:358)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformationVisitor$3.call(ASTTransformationVisitor.java:319)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:923)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:585)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:561)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:538)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:286)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:259)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:674)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:501)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:491)
        at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processOnce(GroovyMain.java:650)
        at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.run(GroovyMain.java:381)
        at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.process(GroovyMain.java:367)
        at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processArgs(GroovyMain.java:126)
        at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.main(GroovyMain.java:106)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:106)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:128)

1 error
```

Already tried looking for cache to blow away in .m2 and .groovy, but found nothing.

Tried setting the user/pass JAVA_OPTS, but no luck with that. Added the following debug setting for ivy

```
groovy -Divy.message.logger.level=4 groovySSHtest.groovy
```

tried it with proxy user/pass, same error

```
groovy -Divy.message.logger.level=4 -Dhttp.proxyUser=user -Dhttp.proxyPassword=pass groovySSHtest.groovy
```

found this additional information

```
Module descriptor is processed : net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.4.0
Module descriptor is processed : net.java.dev.jna#platform;3.4.0
storing dependency org.hidetake#groovy-ssh;1.0.1 in props
        resolved ivy file produced in cache
:: downloading artifacts ::
        [NOT REQUIRED] org.hidetake#groovy-ssh;1.0.1!groovy-ssh.jar
        [NOT REQUIRED] org.codehaus.groovy#groovy-all;2.3.6!groovy-all.jar
        [NOT REQUIRED] org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.7!slf4j-api.jar
        [NOT REQUIRED] com.jcraft#jsch;0.1.51!jsch.jar
        [NOT REQUIRED] com.jcraft#jsch.agentproxy.connector-    factory;0.0.7!jsch.agentproxy.connector-factory.jar(bundle)
        [NOT REQUIRED] com.jcraft#jsch.agentproxy.jsch;0.0.7!jsch.agentproxy.jsch.jar
        [NOT REQUIRED] com.jcraft#jsch.agentproxy.core;0.0.7!jsch.agentproxy.core.jar(bundle)
        [NOT REQUIRED] com.jcraft#jsch.agentproxy.usocket-jna;0.0.7!jsch.agentproxy.usocket-jna.jar(bundle)
        [NOT REQUIRED] com.jcraft#jsch.agentproxy.usocket-nc;0.0.7!jsch.agentproxy.usocket-nc.jar(bundle)
        [NOT REQUIRED] com.jcraft#jsch.agentproxy.sshagent;0.0.7!jsch.agentproxy.sshagent.jar(bundle)
        [NOT REQUIRED] com.jcraft#jsch.agentproxy.pageant;0.0.7!jsch.agentproxy.pageant.jar(bundle)
         trying file:/Users/m673639/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.4.0/jna-3.4.0.jar
                tried file:/Users/m673639/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.4.0/jna-3.4.0.jar
        localm2: resource not reachable for net/java/dev/jna#jna;3.4.0: res=file:/Users/m673639/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.4.0/jna-3.4.0.jar
WARN:   [NOT FOUND  ] net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.4.0!jna.jar (1ms)
WARN: ==== localm2: tried
WARN:   file:/Users/m673639/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.4.0/jna-3.4.0.jar
        [NOT REQUIRED] net.java.dev.jna#platform;3.4.0!platform.jar
        resolve done (371ms resolve - 7ms download)

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
                [NOT FOUND  ] net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.4.0!jna.jar (1ms)

        ==== localm2: tried

          file:/Users/m673639/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.4.0/jna-3.4.0.jar
```

..will try this when WFH on non-corp proxy network to rule that out as possibility.

Comment: i can not reproduce the problem here with direct access to the web.  but @Grap uses ivy, do maybe this helps you debugging further down the line

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me without being behind a proxy, which suggests that you need to [supply your proxy settings to Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/grape.html#Grape-Proxysettings).

```
groovy -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyhost -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 groovySSHtest.groovy
```